# php EOF ignoring new line

Tags: php, text, echo, newline, eof

```
<?php

$mytext = <<<EOF
test {
    gl: 100;
    mkd: 0;
    sld: 0;
}
EOF;



echo $mytext;

?>
```

the output is :

```
test { aaa: black; bbb: yellow; ccc: red; }
```

and I want the output exactly how it's wrote inside the eof segments.

```
test {
    gl: 100;
    mkd: 0;
    sld: 0;
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Don't look in your browser: that will collapse _any_ sequential whitespace to 1 space. Look the _source_ of the page: is that the output you want?

Comment: Yes! On the source it looks fine and this is what I need BUT want to display the end results for the user :) I thought it would be extremely easy :D

Comment: If you're sending this output to the _browser_, it will ignore EOL, collapse whitespace, and glue together fragments. You will need to explicitly add `<br>`'s or use `<pre>` to force multiple lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<pre>` to format the text like that:

```
<?php

$mytext = <<<EOF
<pre>
test {
    gl: 100;
    mkd: 0;
    sld: 0;
}</pre>
EOF;



echo $mytext;

?>
```

Comment: I need to keep the EXACT format since the input would be by the user.

Comment: Yes, you get the userinput in `$strInput` then do: `$strInput = 'test {
    gl: 100;
    mkd: 0;
    sld: 0;
}';

$mytext = <<<EOF
<pre>
$strInput
</pre>
EOF;`

Answer (score 1):

Browser usually ignores control characters, like whitespaces in HTML.

Another solution would be using `echo(`[`nl2br`](https://www.php.net/nl2br)`($mytext))` instead. Which would convert all `\n` into `<br />`.

Converting manually might help You dealing with another kind of whitespaces. Something like this:

```
$replacee = array("\n", "\t");
$replacement = array("<br />", "    ");
$mytext = str_replace($replacee, $replacement, $mytext);
```

Really similar problem linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15409435/1150918) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20414504/1150918) (mostly client side solutions).

Comment: LINE BREAK WORKS NOW BUT WHERE IS THE TABS :)) ?